# Sitecore Link Manager Url Options Site Resolving is not Set

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

In a multisite solution I am using the following solution to allow switching between different link managers based on a site: http://thegrumpycoder.com/post/78684655662/sitecore-pipeline-enabled-linkprovider

This seems to be working as expected. The issue I'm running into is that siteResolving is not being set to true for the following configuration:

```xml
<linkManager defaultProvider="overridesitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
     ...
     <add name="someSiteSpecificLinkManager" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="true" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="always" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="true" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" siteResolving="true"  />
     ...
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

I've switched a few of the other settings just to make sure that they would change the link manager's default url options and they did. Is siteResolving not the correct attribute to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a long-standing issue with `siteResolving` not being applied to the link manager, regardless of it being configured correctly.

The solution is to apply the setting within your provider:

```cs
public class SiteResolvingLinkProvider : LinkProvider
{
    public override UrlOptions GetDefaultUrlOptions()
    {
        UrlOptions urlOptions = base.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
        urlOptions.SiteResolving = Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving;
        return urlOptions;
    }
}
```

See also: http://reasoncodeexample.com/2012/08/09/sitecore-cross-site-links/

It sounds like you have multiple providers, and you are trying to control the setting independently on each provider, correct? In that case, you can try supplying the `siteResolving` attribute on the link provider configuration (as you showed), then read in that configuration into a property on the LinkProvider:

```cs
public bool SiteResolving { get; set; }

public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
{
    base.Initialize(name, config);
    SiteResolving = MainUtil.GetBool(config["siteResolving"], true);
}
```

Comment: I really wanted to avoid adding configuration in code based off a global setting. Is there a way to get the siteResolving attribute from the link manager? I'd rather do that.

Comment: I think the point Derek is making is that the LinkManager does't respect the siteResolving value specified in config, which is the whole problem.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely the problem but I'm asking about a work around I'd prefer as opposed to the one provided.

Comment: Fundamentally, using the "GrumpyCoder" approach requires `siteResolving` to be true. i don't think it works if you set it to false. So while I agree that applying config in code is not great. In this case you can't really call it config at all - it's a requirement.

Comment: How so? It may need to be set in the global default url options by setting Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving to have a value of true but siteResolving means nothing in the link manager unless it is read in as Derek updated his answer to show. @Derek that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!